# Styled components with React context

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components, preact

I want to use normal React context with styled-components. I am aware of generic theme providers in styled-components, however, it will be much better if I will be able to do this by using React.useContext(). Do you know is it possible? I tried something like this.

useConfig

```
export function useConfig() {
  const configCtx = useContext<ConfigContextShape | undefined>(ConfigContext)
  return configCtx
}
```

example styled.ts

```
import { useConfig } from 'state'
import styled from 'styled-components'
const { background_color } = useConfig()

export const VisualSearchWrapper = styled.main`
  color: black;
  background-color: ${background_color};
`
```

I will be appreciated for any help.

One more update:
In the example this issue occurred:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'context')
```

The ConfigContextProvider is below

```
import { createContext } from 'preact'
import { FC } from 'preact/compat'
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'preact/hooks'

export interface ConfigProfile {
  background_color: string
}

interface ConfigFunctions {
  updateConfigState: (updatedConfig: ConfigProfile) => void
}

type ConfigContextShape = ConfigProfile & ConfigFunctions

export const ConfigContext = createContext<ConfigContextShape | undefined>(undefined)

export const ConfigContextProvider: FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [localState, setLocalState] = useState<ConfigProfile>({
    background_color: '',
  })

  function updateConfigState(updatedConfig: ConfigProfile) {
    setLocalState({ ...localState, ...updatedConfig })
  }

  const ctxValue: ConfigContextShape = {
    background_color: localState?.background_color ?? '',
    updateConfigState
  }

  return <ConfigContext.Provider value={ctxValue}>{children}</ConfigContext.Provider>
}

export function useConfig() {
  const configCtx = useContext<ConfigContextShape>(ConfigContext)
  if (configCtx === undefined) {
    throw new Error('useConfig must be used within a ConfigProvider')
  }
  return configCtx
}
```

Comment: 1. the import of `useConfig ` looks wrong.  2. Add the code from your `context.provider`

Comment: Import is good. I am able to fully useConfig in normal files.